# Crear una curva de Berzier con N puntos Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, matemáticas

Estuve investigando bastante y no encontré en ninguna parte alguna forma de hacer una Curva de Berzier libremente, siempre condicionado con funciones, de estar en lo contrario, agradecería que me corrigiera en mi error. Y al menos con canvas se encuentran varias formas predeterminadas para hacerlo.

Como por ejemplo:

```
context.quadraticCurveTo(130,5,180,160);

context.bezierCurveTo(10,40,120,-30,190,190);
```

Y según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curva_de_B%C3%A9zier):

La formula para las **Curvas lineales de Bézier**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La formula para las **Curvas cuadráticas de Bézier**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por último, la formula para las **Curvas cúbicas de Bézier**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como yo lo veo en las tres funciones siempre hay un patrón, el cual es marcada por la generalización.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta eso, se me ocurrió este pequeño ejemplo que realiza lo que la generalización indica

```js
(function () {
    'use strict'
    var canvas, context, Sx, Sy, x, y, scale; // Estas son declaraciones de variables

    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    Sx = (window.innerWidth - (window.innerWidth * .011));
    canvas.width = Sx;
    Sy = (window.innerHeight - (window.innerHeight * .15));
    canvas.height = Sy;
    x = Sx / 2;
    y = Sy / 2;
    scale = 5;

    function clear() { // Función para limpiar canvas
        context.clearRect(0, 0, Sx, Sy);
    }

    function grid() { // Función para crear el background
        context.lineWidth = .5;
        context.strokeStyle = '#00ffee';
        context.beginPath();
        for (let i = x; i < Sx; i += scale) {
            context.moveTo(i, 0);
            context.lineTo(i, Sy);
        }
        for (let i = x; i > 0; i -= scale) {
            context.moveTo(i, 0);
            context.lineTo(i, Sy);
        }
        for (let i = y; i < Sy; i += scale) {
            context.moveTo(0, i);
            context.lineTo(Sx, i);
        }
        for (let i = y; i > 0; i -= scale) {
            context.moveTo(0, i);
            context.lineTo(Sx, i);
        }
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }


    function calPoint([nx, ny]) { 

// Esta función es para poder transformar las coordenadas en coordenadas según canvas, 
// ya que canvas solo cuenta un cuadro que inicia con la parte superior izquierda
// Por lo que  requiere una conversión

        return [x + nx * scale, y - ny * scale];
    }

    function berzierPoints(Points, t) {

// Esta función es la encargada de transformar todos los puntos en puntos de berzier según *t*

        let val = Points.length - 1;
        let x = 0, y = 0; // Ya que los puntos son el resultados de la suma del seguimiento, se inicializan a cero
        for (let i = 0; i < Points.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) { // La primera coordenada siempre recibirá este parámetro
                x += Points[i].x * Math.pow(1 - t, val);
                y += Points[i].y * Math.pow(1 - t, val);
            } else if (i == val) { // Al igual que el último
                x += Points[i].x * Math.pow(t, i);
                y += Points[i].y * Math.pow(t, i);
            } else { // Los demás siempre serán la multiplicación de la cantidad de puntos sin contar el primero 
// Después t se elevará según su posición y se multiplicará
// Y por último (1 - t) se elevará a la cantidad de puntos (sin contar el primero) menos su posición
                x += Points[i].x * val * Math.pow(t, i) * Math.pow(1 - t, val - i);
                y += Points[i].y * val * Math.pow(t, i) * Math.pow(1 - t, val - i);
            }
        }
        return calPoint([x, y]);
    }

    function berzier(Points) {
// Lo siguiente es para poder ubicar los puntos en el plano a través de cirulos rojos
        for (let i = 0; i < Points.length; i++) {
            context.strokeStyle = 'red';
            context.beginPath();
            let [x, y] = calPoint([Points[i].x, Points[i].y]);
            context.arc(x, y, scale, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();
        }
        context.strokeStyle = 'purple';
        context.beginPath();
        let [x, y] = berzierPoints(Points, 0.001);
// Se debe iniciar con la parte más pequeña de una centésima ingresandola cono *t*
        context.moveTo(x, y);
// De ahí avanza el recorrimiento en 0.001 cada ciclo hasta llegar a 1
        for (let i = 0.002; i <= 1; i += 0.001) {
            let [x, y] = berzierPoints(Points, i);
            context.lineTo(x, y);
        }
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }

    function xy() { // Función para dibujar lineas de X & Y
        context.strokeStyle = '#000';
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(Sx, y);
        context.stroke();
        context.moveTo(x, 0);
        context.lineTo(x, Sy);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
        context.font = "20px Arial";
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fillText("Y", x - 20, 20);
        context.fillText("X", Sx - 20, y + 20);
    }

    function draw() {
        grid();
        xy();
    }

    document.getElementById('draw').addEventListener('click', e => {
        let x = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=X]'), // Busca todos los inputs que inicien con X
            y = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=Y]'), // Buscan todos los inputs que inicien con Y
            Points = new Array(), // Crea el arreglo de los puntos de coordeadas
            cont = 0; // Ya que posiblemente no se llenarán todos los inputs se busca llenarlos según sean aceptados
        for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (!isNaN(x[i].value) && x[i].value != '' && !isNaN(y[i].value) && y[i].value != '') {
                Points[cont] = {
                    x: parseFloat(x[i].value),
                    y: parseFloat(y[i].value)
                }
                cont++;
            }
        }
        clear();
        grid();
        berzier(Points);  // Y lo introduce en la función Berzier
        xy();
    });

    draw();
})();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: solid black;
}

input {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Berzier</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <input type="number" id="X" placeholder="x">
    <input type="number" id="Y" placeholder="y">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X1" placeholder="x1">
    <input type="number" id="Y1" placeholder="y1">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X2" placeholder="x2">
    <input type="number" id="Y2" placeholder="y2">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X3" placeholder="x3">
    <input type="number" id="Y3" placeholder="y3">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X4" placeholder="x4">
    <input type="number" id="Y4" placeholder="y4">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X5" placeholder="x5">
    <input type="number" id="Y5" placeholder="y5">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X6" placeholder="x6">
    <input type="number" id="Y6" placeholder="y6">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X7" placeholder="x7">
    <input type="number" id="Y7" placeholder="y7">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X8" placeholder="x8">
    <input type="number" id="Y8" placeholder="y8">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X9" placeholder="x9">
    <input type="number" id="Y9" placeholder="y9">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X10" placeholder="x10">
    <input type="number" id="Y10" placeholder="y10">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X11" placeholder="x11">
    <input type="number" id="Y11" placeholder="y11">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X12" placeholder="x12">
    <input type="number" id="Y12" placeholder="y12">
    ||
    <input type="number" id="X13" placeholder="x13">
    <input type="number" id="Y13" placeholder="y13">
    <hr />
    <button id="draw">Draw</button>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```